# What is -moz-border-radius used for?

Tags: css, firefox

Can someone tell me what `-moz-border-radius` is used for?

I understand it is one of Mozilla CSS Extensions but I don't understand what really it is used for.

I tried the following example in Firefox and both `border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius` do the same thing.

See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/CPmt7/) in Firefox.

Thanks.

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser vendors often use a prefix (like `-moz-` or `-webkit-` etc) to implement features before they become a standard. For backwards compatibility they sometimes keep supporting the prefixed versions after standardization.

I actually think that in the case of `-moz-border-radius`, `border-radius` is not exactly identical as Mozilla implemented the `border-radius` property differently to how the spec finally turned out, whereas everybody else implemented the standard. You won't notice a difference if you only use one value for it though (`-moz-border-radius: 10px` and `border-radius: 10px` behaves the same, but `-moz-border-radius: 10px 8px 4px 12px` and `border-radius: 10px 8px 4px 12px` do not (unless I'm misstaken)).

Comment: `-moz-border-radius` was one of the scratchiest prefixed CSS3 properties when it was first implemented in Firefox 2, with **no anti-aliasing** on round corners.

Comment: Actually, `-moz-border-radius` is just an alias for `border-radius` now; Mozilla does not keep the old broken behavior for prefixed properties, unlike some other browsers, when implementing the final spec.

Answer (score 3):

`-moz-border-radius` is just an older version of the property.  You can see the relevant versions in the [compatability table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius#Browser_compatibility) at MDN.

> In Gecko 2.0 -moz-border-radius is renamed to border-radius. -moz-border-radius was supported as an alias  until Gecko 12.0 included. In order to conform to the CSS3 standard, Gecko 2.0:
>
> - changes the handling of  values to match the specification. You can specify an ellipse as border on an arbitrary sized element just with border-radius: 50%;
> - makes rounded corners clip content and images (if overflow : visible is not set)
>
> Note: Support for the prefixed version (-moz-border-radius) was removed in Gecko 13.0 (Firefox 13.0 / Thunderbird 13.0) .

Comment: Thank you @Dennis for your answer and including the link to the Browser compatibility table.

Answer (score 0):

[`border-radius` is a CSS3 property which is part of the 'Border' module.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/#the-border-radius)

`-moz-border-radius` is the Mozilla draft implementation of this CSS3 property.

> Mozilla supports a number of extensions to CSS that are prefixed with -moz-.
>
> Some of these properties have been included in draft CSS specification for inclusion in the final recommendation, but are still experimental. The final standard property may be different from the current prefix implementation. Some of these non-standard properties apply only to XUL elements.
>
> Once standardized, and the support for the un-prefixed variant added, the prefixed properties are dropped. [[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions#Mozilla-prefixed_properties_on_the_standard_track)]